# Why the sum of these variables returning negative zero?

Tags: php

I found out recently that my code is generating negative zeroes. And this is my very first time encountering this scenario since 3 years ago.

The code was something like this:

```
$x =  "300.20";
$y =  ("300.10" + "0.10" + "0.00") - "0.00";
$z =  $x - $y;
```

The `$x` returns string, `$y` and `$z` return float. If you run this codes, `$z`'s value is -5.6843418860808E-14, using `number_format` it will become `-0.00`.

Also, `$y`'s value is `300.20` but it is not equal to `300.20` when comparing. Exactly same value but not equal.

My solution is to convert `$y` to string: `$z =  $x - strval($y);` but the question is why is this happening?

Same output in PHP5 and PHP7

Comment: `float` number problem is all the same in all languages. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript . The "300.20", "300.10" and "0.10" are float numbers with precision problem

Comment: _Side note:_ When working with numbers, there's no reason to quote the values. Just use them as is: `$x = 300.20;` etc.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson those values are generated from database, which I don't have the power to change that datatype. but can only converted via PHP

Comment: @ADyson you said "in the code above", and I said "The code was **something** like this:". because the real code is `$row['AMT']` generated from mysql query, I just represent the code something like that for better understanding.